# How to insert an elements from vector into matrix based on array of random indexes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, torch

Basicly, im trying to insert an elements from vector into matrix based on random index

```
size = 100000
answer_count = 4
num_range = int(1e4)

a = torch.randint(-num_range, num_range, size=(size, ))
b = torch.randint(-num_range, num_range, size=(size, ))
answers = torch.randint(-num_range, num_range, size=(size, answer_count))

for i in range(size): answers[i, np.random.randint(answer_count)] = a[i] + b[i]
```

I tried something like

```
c = a + b
pos = torch.randint(answer_count, size=(size, ))
answers[:, pos] = c
```

But i'm certainly doing something wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change the last line like this:

```
answers[np.arange(size), pos] = c
```

The problem lies in incorrect use of advanced indexing. To understand the difference of those indexing try printing out `answers[:, pos]` vs. `answers[np.arange(size), pos]` and you will see why the previous one does not work. `answers[np.arange(size), pos]` selects each `pos` with **a single row** while `answers[:, pos]` selects **ALL rows** with each `pos`. More information on advanced indexing in [numpy doc here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html).